# How do I determine the input voltage for a solid state relay?

Tags: voltage, current, resistors, solid-state-relay

5v + 1k ohm resistor input to PVG612PBF (SSRelay) [Datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-PVG612-DataSheet-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535683c1892937)

Is this the correct voltage/resistor to suit this relay?

If not, how would the voltage or resistor be selected for this specific SSR?

How do I read the datasheet to arrive at an input voltage for an SSR?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

*Figure 1. The IR LED should have a V<sub>F</sub> of about 1.4 V. Image source: [LEDnique](http://lednique.com/current-voltage-relationships/iv-curves/).*

The internal LED is an infrared type with a forward current of 5 to 25 mA.  and a forward voltage drop of about 1.4 V. You can treat this as any other LED. On a 5 V supply your resistor will drop about 3.6 V. A 1 kΩ resistor would therefore limit the current to about 3.6 mA which is a bit low. Aim for 10 mA (mid-range) which will give you \$ R = \frac V I = \frac {3.6}{20m} = 0.18\ \text k \Omega \$ (where 'm' is for milli). So 180 Ω.

Answer (score 1):

> *How do I read the datasheet to arrive at an input voltage for an SSR?*

Take a look in the [data sheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-PVG612-DataSheet-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535683c1892937) at this table and this graph: -
$$$$

[image]

So, if you decide on (say) 10 mA forward current into the input, you can expect a forward volt drop on the IR diode of about 1.2 volts at ambient temperatures. If your required input control voltage is (say) 5 volts, the voltage across the (required) series resistor will be 5 volts minus 1.2 volts = 3.8 volts. And, to get 10 mA flowing, the resistor value will be 3.8/0.01 = 380 Ω.

Answer (score 0):

$$R=\dfrac{V_{cc}-V_F}{I_F}$$

Where Vcc is the supply voltage, Vf is the forward voltage drop on LED and If is the LED current.

[Datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-PVG612-DataSheet-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535683c1892937)

[image]

Example:

$$R=\dfrac{V_{cc}-1.25V}{15mA}$$

R=270 Ohm:

$$R_{min}=\dfrac{5V-1V}{20mA}=200\Omega$$

$$R_{max}=\dfrac{5V-1.5V}{7mA}=500 \Omega$$

As the minimum current declared is 5mA and the absolute maximum is 25mA, I would choose a 330 Ohm resistor to be in between both limits when cold and warm.

Comment: Marko, could you please provide a link to the original source of the graphic you copied into your answer? It is site policy to provide attribution for included material.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Ok, I have dne, but it is already in the OP's question - datasheet.